# Filtered range (circular) traversal starting from iterator over original sequence

Tags: c++, range-v3

Say you have a container and have an iterator to some element of that container. The requirement is to circularly advance that iterator but with a filter. Now, creating a filtered (circular) view over the sequence is trivial but how do you initiate the traversal when all you have is an iterator over the original? I was thinking about concatenating two ranges, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
using namespace ranges;

int main () {
    std::vector< int > xs{ -4, 1, 3, -4, 2, -3, 6, 7, 8, -9, -10 };

    auto iter = xs.begin ();
    std::advance (iter, 8);

    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;

    auto lhs = make_subrange (iter, xs.end ());
    auto rhs = make_subrange (xs.begin (), iter);

    auto is_pos = [](auto x) { return x >= 0; };
    auto rng = views::cycle (views::concat (lhs, rhs) | views::filter (is_pos));

    auto next = ++rng.begin ();
    std::cout << *next << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a simpler approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instead of concatenating 2 sub-ranges at `iter`, you could simply `drop` the elements before `iter`.

So this snippet

```
auto lhs = make_subrange (iter, xs.end ());
auto rhs = make_subrange (xs.begin (), iter);

auto rng = views::cycle (views::concat (lhs, rhs) | views::filter (is_pos));
```

becomes

```
auto rng = xs | views::cycle
              | views::drop(distance(xs.begin(), iter))
              | views::filter(is_pos);
```

Note that while this solution is *simpler*, it cycles over all the unfiltered elements, and applies the filter predicate multiple times. Your solution is probably more *efficient* than this one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the intention is to find the next element if not in the remaining elements, between iter and end, then in the elements between beg and iter. IOW, when the search starts somewhere in the middle of the container, wraparound and  restart from the beginning.
EDIT: I misunderstood your solution. Now I think I got it.